# Custom AxisRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark, flex-charting, flex-charts

I am working with a `LineChart` with a `CategoryAxis` for the horizontal axis and I need each category to have a very custom formatted display.  Using `CategoryAxis.LabelFunction` is not powerful enough for my purposes, as it only allows custom formatting of the text field of a Label object.  Specifically for this project I need each category to be a grid or HGroup of two different multi-line labels.  The left label needs to be left aligned and the right to be right aligned.

I tried creating a custom class that `extends Group` and `implements IDataRenderer`.  However, the `public function set data(value:Object)`, defined in `IDataRenderer`, always seems to be called with value as an `AxisLabel` object, which does not pass an Object within it, just a string (`AxisLabel.text`)

---

As a hack-ey alternative, I tried using the LabelFunction to pass an encoded string but even that causes problems.  Somehow this code causes nothing to be displayed on the CategoryAxis:

```
public class HeatmapAxisLabelRenderer 
extends HGroup
implements IDataRenderer
{
public function HeatmapAxisLabelRenderer()
{
    super();

    this.includeInLayout = true;
    this.visible = true;

    this.width = 100;
    this.height = 40;
//      this.percentWidth = 100;
//      this.percentHeight = 100;
}


// Internal variable for the property value.
private var _data:Object;

// Make the data property bindable.
[Bindable("dataChange")]

// Define the getter method.
public function get data():Object {
    return _data;
}

// Define the setter method, and dispatch an event when the property
// changes to support data binding.
public function set data(value:Object):void {
    _data = value;

    if (value is AxisLabel && AxisLabel(value).text!=null) {
        var parts:Array = AxisLabel(value).text.split("|~|");
        if (parts.length != 2) return;

        var name:Label = new Label();
        name.text = parts[0];
        name.setStyle("textAlign","left");
        name.width = 100;

        var limit:Label = new Label();
        limit.text = parts[1];
        limit.setStyle("textAlign","right");
        limit.width = 100;

        this.addElement(name);
        this.addElement(limit);

        dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));
    } else {
        trace("renderer bad value");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be a weird interaction between `Group` and `AxisRenderer`, and the fact that your renderer (an `HGroup`) has explicit width/height values (set in its constructor):

After setting the `data` on your custom renderer, AxisRenderer` tells the custom renderer to invalidate it's size.

While doing so, the `Group` correctly decides not to do anything because it has an explicit width/height.

I made some changes to get this to work:

- only set the width in the constructor
- don't set width on child labels (you will likely want to play w/this)
- made the label objects member variables, and create them only once in create children (the setter for data may get called frequently)

Code:

```
package
{
    import mx.charts.AxisLabel;
    import mx.core.IDataRenderer;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    import spark.components.HGroup;
    import spark.components.Label;

    public class HeatmapAxisLabelRenderer extends HGroup implements IDataRenderer
    {
        public function HeatmapAxisLabelRenderer()
        {
            super();
            this.width=100;
        }

        private var _data:Object;

        [Bindable("dataChange")]
        public function get data():Object {
                return _data;
        }

        private var nameLabel:Label;
        private var limit:Label;

        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();
            if (!nameLabel)
            {
                nameLabel=new Label();
                nameLabel.setStyle("textAlign","left");
                limit = new Label();
                limit.setStyle("textAlign", "right");
                addElement(nameLabel);
                addElement(limit);
            }
        }

        public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            if (_data === value)
                return;

            _data = value;
            if (value is AxisLabel && AxisLabel(value).text!=null)
            {
                var parts:Array = AxisLabel(value).text.split("|~|");
                if (parts.length == 2)
                {
                    nameLabel.text = parts[0];
                    limit.text = parts[1];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                trace("renderer bad value");
            }
            dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));
        }
    }
}
```